# Finding a Javascript Event that Blocks All Others

Tags: jquery, plupload

I am working on a project that uses the plUpload library.

After I upload files using plUpload, all further jQuery events on the page stop working (including my dropdown menu, DataTables, and a few other elements with `.live("click"`).

I have spent many hours stepping through the script in the Chrome console and I have not found anything that would cause the problem.

<strike>I think the entire code would be too much to post here, so I am looking for suggestions of what would cause something like this or where to put breakpoints to help figure it out.</strike>

---

EDIT: Based on the suggestions/answers below, here is the offending code:

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
    uploadSuccess(file, response.response);
});

function uploadSuccess(fileObj, serverData) {
    var item = jQuery('#upload-item-' + fileObj.id);

    // on success serverData should be numeric, fix bug in html4 runtime returning the serverData wrapped in a <pre> tag
    serverData = serverData.replace(/^<pre>(\d+)<\/pre>$/, '$1');

    if ( serverData.match(/upload-error|error-div/) ) {
        item.html(serverData);
        return;
    } else {
        jQuery('.progress', item).hide();
        jQuery('.closebtn', item).show();
    }

    [...]
}
```

`serverData` was wrapped in a skin which included a new call to instantiate `jQuery`. Once I removed the skin, it worked properly.

Comment: a transparent div over the entire page would make it tough to interact with the page.

Comment: Do ordinary links still work?

Comment: @KevinB Hover effects still work as do regular links, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Does the upload callback function modify the DOM? If it's too big to post here, can you post a link?

Comment: The upload callback does different actions depending on the returned format. If it is a number, it is passed on to an AJAX request for more information. Otherwise, it is just appended to the progress bar element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds like your upload callback is just blindly dumping the server's response into the page.  If the server's response is an HTML response, make sure it does not contain any script tags that could be messing with your page.  I have seen this happen in cases where a site was using a template system that automatically wrapped all output in the site's template unless specifically directed not to.  When a developer forgot to do so, the upload callback included a new copy of jQuery and cleared out all of the click events.

Comment: That was it. I will update my question with the relevant code.